# Convert row in csv file to menu

Tags: python

I have a csv file named codes.csv as below.

```
CATEGORY            SUB-CATEGORY
Technology          Accessories
Technology          Phones
Technology          Copier
Technology          Machines
Furniture           Chairs
Furniture           Tables
Furniture           Bookcase
Office Supplies         Appliances
Office Supplies         Stationery
Office Supplies         Binders
```

I would like to print it out in the program as a menu like below:

```
Choose a Sub Catgory:
    1:Technology
    2:Furniture
    3:Office Supplies
    Enter a Catgory:2

    Choose a Sub Catgory:
    1:Chairs
    2:Tables
    3:Bookcase
    Enter a Sub Catgory:1
```

If the user selects 2 (Furniture) in Category, then the program will print out the sub-categories, like Chairs, Tables, and Bookcase, which are under Furniture.

I'm able to print out the categories as a menu, but when the user keys in the option, the program does nothing.

```
import csv
filePath1 = "codes.csv"
print("Choose a Category : ")
categories = {}
sub_categories = {}
option = 0
with open(filePath1) as csvfile:  # open category file
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  # dictread file
        for row in reader:
                categories[row['CATEGORY']] = 0               

for key,value in categories.items():
        option = option + 1
        print("{:>1} : {:<20}".format(option,key))

category = input("Enter Category : ")
if(category == option):
        print(option)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is the formatting of you data. It seems like you've used spaces as separators which entails two problems:

1. One of your data points contains a space, too. That's ambiguous and will mess up your parsing.
2. You have many spaces as separators between the columns. I'm not sure if it's possible to do that in csv but it won't simplify things.

What is the original data formatting? Maybe you've tabs in your original data which have been converted while copying pasting it here.
From here on, I assume that there is one tab (`\t`) between the columns.

When I run the code, I get an error:

```
Choose a Category :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x.py", line 12, in <module>
    categories[row['CATEGORY']] = 0
KeyError: 'CATEGORY'
```

That's because the `csv.DictReader` does not understand the formatting. It's strange that you don't get an error like that, I guess it's because you have some other data formatting. For tab-separated columns we need an additional argument:

```
with open(filePath1) as csvfile:  # open category file
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')  # dictread file
    for row in reader:
        categories[row['CATEGORY']] = 0
```

Then you have the problem of comparing `int` with `str` in the last section. Fix it by converting the string to an integer first:

```
try:
    category = int(input("Enter Category : "))
    if category == option:
            print(option)
except ValueError:
    print("Try again with a valid category")
```

Finally, one logical problem remains: In the end, `option` is the number of categories you have, so this does not make any sense to me at all.
How about this?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import sys

filePath1 = "codes.csv"

with open(filePath1) as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    categories = [ row["CATEGORY"] for row in reader ]

# eliminate duplicates, but also destroys the order
categories = list(set(categories))

for i, category in enumerate(categories):
    print("{}: {}".format(i, category))

try:
    option = int(input("Enter Category: "))
except ValueError:
    print("Try again with a valid integer.")
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    category = categories[option]
    print(category)
except IndexError:
    print("Value out of bounds.")
    sys.exit(1)

# Do something with category...
```

Comment: Thank you for answering me. I tried to convert category to int as [ category = int(input("Enter Category : ")) ],but still unable to catch the option.

Comment: I've just run your code and it doesn't even parse the csv file correctly. For me, it terminates with an error message. Now I'm confused since you've said that "when user key it the option, program do nothing". Do you also get the error message "KeyError: 'CATEGORY'"? Please update your question.

Comment: hi, pasbi. I didn't get any error message. It's like ntg happen after I key the option. I tried to add else: print("NTG"). And re-run the program, and it is print out the NTG. not the option I want.

Comment: Thank you. But I'm getting the builtins.KeyError: 'CATEGORY' in line [ reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
        categories = row['CATEGORY'] ]

Comment: As I said, I don't know what data format you actually use. I suspect that snippet you've posted has been reformatted by StackOverflow and hence is useless here. Post your original data file somewhere. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47689/how-can-i-attach-a-file-to-a-post

Comment: I shared it in my google, please have a look.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bR-GjrOcC80Wj1yK60eKeKP2JvKNl3JG/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Well, that looks like comma separated columns, doesn't it? I think you know what to change (tip: It's in the line starting with `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter='\t')`). And please! Post your original data next time. It would have saved so much trouble...

Comment: I'm sorry about it. Thank you so much for your help. Can I ask one more question ? How can I set the list is start from 1 not 0?

Comment: You must try to think about that yourself if you want to improve your skills. It's really trivially simple. Search for the line where the numbers are printed and figure out how that line works and how to do simple mathematical calculations...